# Do I have to worry about anything with regard to URL rewrite in a shared hosting?

Tags: asp.net, mod-rewrite, shared-hosting

I'm buiding an ASP.NET website using a rewrite module (UrlRewriting.net) and I plan to deploy it in a shared hosting environment (possibly DiscountAsp.net)

Do I have to worry about anything?

One thing that I'm concerned is about whether or not I can make extensionless rewriting..
for intance: `foo.com/123/blablabla` instead of `foo.com/123/blablabla.aspx`

I'm afraid of having a lot of work and in the end it doesn't work :)

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to check with the host to confirm.  They need to put you on IIS7 with URL Rewrite installed and integrated mode for the app pool. With that configuration you should be good, including extensionless rewriting.